# C# OpenXML copy and paste excel sheet to new workbook

Tags: c#, openxml

I have multiple workbooks with the same sheet name. I want to copy all the individual sheets to one workbook. The code I have so far copies the text but it doesn't keep formatting , so I lose the colors, borders etc. Can someone suggest any improvements to include styles also and keep formatting? Thanks

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Linq;
namespace openxmlExcelTryout
{


class OpenXMLCopySheet
{
    private static int tableId;

    public static void CopySheet(string filename, string sheetName, string clonedSheetName, string destFileName)
    {

        //Open workbook
        using (SpreadsheetDocument mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = mySpreadsheet.WorkbookPart;
            //Get the source sheet to be copied
            WorksheetPart sourceSheetPart = GetWorkSheetPart(workbookPart, sheetName);
            SharedStringTablePart sharedStringTable = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
            //Take advantage of AddPart for deep cloning
            using (SpreadsheetDocument newXLFile = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destFileName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                WorkbookPart newWorkbookPart = newXLFile.AddWorkbookPart();
                SharedStringTablePart newSharedStringTable = newWorkbookPart.AddPart<SharedStringTablePart>(sharedStringTable);
                WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart = newWorkbookPart.AddPart<WorksheetPart>(sourceSheetPart);
                //Table definition parts are somewhat special and need unique ids...so let's make an id based on count
                int numTableDefParts = sourceSheetPart.GetPartsCountOfType<TableDefinitionPart>();
                tableId = numTableDefParts;

                //Clean up table definition parts (tables need unique ids)
                if (numTableDefParts != 0)
                    FixupTableParts(newWorksheetPart, numTableDefParts);
                //There should only be one sheet that has focus
                CleanView(newWorksheetPart);

                var fileVersion = new FileVersion { ApplicationName = "Microsoft Office Excel" };

                //Worksheet ws = newWorksheetPart.Worksheet;
                Workbook wb = new Workbook();
                wb.Append(fileVersion);

                //Add new sheet to main workbook part
                Sheets sheets = null;
                //int sheetCount = wb.Sheets.Count();
                if (wb.Sheets != null)
                { sheets = wb.GetFirstChild<Sheets>(); }
                else
                { sheets = new Sheets(); }

                Sheet copiedSheet = new Sheet
                {
                    Name = clonedSheetName,
                    Id = newWorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart)
                };
                if (wb.Sheets != null)
                { copiedSheet.SheetId = (uint)sheets.ChildElements.Count + 1; }
                else { copiedSheet.SheetId = 1; }

                sheets.Append(copiedSheet);
                newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

                wb.Append(sheets);
                //Save Changes
                newWorkbookPart.Workbook = wb;
                wb.Save();
                newXLFile.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    static void CleanView(WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
    {
        //There can only be one sheet that has focus
        SheetViews views = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetViews>();

        if (views != null)
        {
            views.Remove();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
        }
    }

    static void FixupTableParts(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, int numTableDefParts)
    {
        //Every table needs a unique id and name
        foreach (TableDefinitionPart tableDefPart in worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts)
        {
            tableId++;
            tableDefPart.Table.Id = (uint)tableId;
            tableDefPart.Table.DisplayName = "CopiedTable" + tableId;
            tableDefPart.Table.Name = "CopiedTable" + tableId;
            tableDefPart.Table.Save();
        }
    }
    static WorksheetPart GetWorkSheetPart(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string sheetName)
    {
        //Get the relationship id of the sheetname
        string relId = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>()
            .Where(s => s.Name.Value.Equals(sheetName))
            .First()
            .Id;

        return (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relId);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution and post it here maybe someone will get some help from it.

```
public static void MergeXSLX(string spreadSheetPathSource, string spreadSheetPathDestination)
    {
        //string[] staticSheets = new string[] { "Index", "Proj Info", "Project Report", "Cust Proj Rpt", "Issues Register", "Risk Register", "Change Register", "Milestones Register", "Add Optional Sheets ==>" };

        string[] staticSheets = new string[] { "Summaries", "limits" };

        FileStream spreadSheetStreamSource = null;
        FileStream spreadSheetStreamDestination = null;
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(spreadSheetPathSource)) throw new Exception("Source excel document not found!");
            if (!File.Exists(spreadSheetPathDestination)) throw new Exception("Destination excel document not found!");
            spreadSheetStreamSource = new FileStream(spreadSheetPathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            spreadSheetStreamDestination = new FileStream(spreadSheetPathDestination, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocumentSource = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(spreadSheetStreamSource, false))
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocumentDestination = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(spreadSheetStreamDestination, true))
                {
                    WorkbookPart workbookPartSource = spreadsheetDocumentSource.WorkbookPart;
                    WorkbookPart workbookPartDestination = spreadsheetDocumentDestination.WorkbookPart;

                    foreach (Sheet sheet in workbookPartSource.Workbook.Sheets)
                    {
                        if (staticSheets.ToList().Contains(sheet.Name))
                        {
                            uint replaced = 0;
                            int index = 0;

                            if (workbookPartDestination.Workbook.Sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count(s => s.Name.ToString().Equals(sheet.Name)) == 1)
                            {
                                Sheet org;
                                foreach (Sheet s in workbookPartDestination.Workbook.Sheets.Elements<Sheet>())
                                {
                                    if (s.Name.ToString().Equals(sheet.Name))
                                    {
                                        org = s;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    index++;
                                }

                                replaced = sheet.SheetId;

                                DeleteWorkSheet(workbookPartDestination, sheet.Name);
                            }

                            //WorkbookPart workbookPart = mySpreadsheet.WorkbookPart;
                            ////Get the source sheet to be copied
                            WorksheetPart sourceSheetPart = GetWorkSheetPart(workbookPartSource, sheet.Name);

                            //Take advantage of AddPart for deep cloning
                            SpreadsheetDocument tempSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(new MemoryStream(), spreadsheetDocumentDestination.DocumentType);
                            WorkbookPart tempWorkbookPart = tempSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
                            WorksheetPart tempWorksheetPart = tempWorkbookPart.AddPart<WorksheetPart>(sourceSheetPart);

                            if(workbookPartDestination.SharedStringTablePart == null)
                            {
                                workbookPartDestination.AddPart<SharedStringTablePart>(workbookPartSource.SharedStringTablePart);
                            }

                            //Add cloned sheet and all associated parts to workbook
                            WorksheetPart clonedSheet = workbookPartDestination.AddPart<WorksheetPart>(tempWorksheetPart);

                            //Table definition parts are somewhat special and need unique ids...so let's make an id based on count
                            int numTableDefParts = sourceSheetPart.GetPartsCountOfType<TableDefinitionPart>();
                            int tableId = numTableDefParts;

                            //Clean up table definition parts (tables need unique ids)
                            if (numTableDefParts != 0)
                                FixupTableParts(clonedSheet, numTableDefParts);
                            //There should only be one sheet that has focus
                            CleanView(clonedSheet);

                            var values = workbookPartSource.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ToArray();

                            Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheCellFormat = new Dictionary<uint, uint>();
                            Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheCellStyleFormat = new Dictionary<uint, uint>();
                            Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheBorder = new Dictionary<uint, uint>();
                            Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheFill = new Dictionary<uint, uint>();
                            Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheFont = new Dictionary<uint, uint>();
                            Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheNumberFormat = new Dictionary<uint, uint>();
                            foreach (Cell cell in clonedSheet.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>())
                            {
                                if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
                                {
                                    var ssindex = int.Parse(cell.CellValue.Text);
                                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(InsertSharedStringItem_(values[ssindex].InnerText, workbookPartDestination.SharedStringTablePart).ToString());
                                }

                                if (cell.StyleIndex != null)
                                {
                                    cell.StyleIndex = GetCellFormat(workbookPartSource, workbookPartDestination, cacheCellFormat, cacheCellStyleFormat, cacheBorder, cacheFill, cacheFont, cacheNumberFormat, cell);
                                }
                            }

                            //Add new sheet to main workbook part
                            Sheets sheets = workbookPartDestination.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
                            Sheet copiedSheet = new Sheet
                            {
                                Name = sheet.Name,
                                Id = workbookPartDestination.GetIdOfPart(clonedSheet),
                                SheetId = (uint)sheets.ChildElements.Count + 1
                            };

                            if (replaced != 0)
                            {
                                copiedSheet.SheetId = replaced;
                                sheets.InsertAt(copiedSheet, index);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sheets.Append(copiedSheet);
                            }

                            //Save Changes
                            workbookPartDestination.Workbook.Save();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (spreadSheetStreamSource != null)
                spreadSheetStreamSource.Close();
            if (spreadSheetStreamDestination != null)
                spreadSheetStreamDestination.Close();
        }



    }



    private static uint GetCellFormat(WorkbookPart workbookPartSource, WorkbookPart workbookPartDestination, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheCellFormat, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheCellStyleFormat, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheBorder, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheFill, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheFont, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheNumberFormat, Cell cell)

    {

        uint cellFormatIndex, cellStyleFormatIndex;

        if (cacheCellFormat.Keys.Contains(cell.StyleIndex.Value))

        {

            cellFormatIndex = cacheCellFormat[cell.StyleIndex.Value];

        }

        else

        {

            CellFormat cellFormat = workbookPartSource.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Descendants<CellFormat>().ToList()[int.Parse(cell.StyleIndex)];

            CellFormat cellFormatClone = CellFormatClone(workbookPartSource, workbookPartDestination, cacheBorder, cacheFill, cacheFont, cacheNumberFormat, cellFormat);

            if (cellFormat.FormatId != 0)

            {

                if (cacheCellStyleFormat.Keys.Contains(cellFormat.FormatId.Value))

                {

                    cellStyleFormatIndex = cacheCellStyleFormat[cellFormat.FormatId.Value];

                }

                else

                {

                    CellFormat cellStyleFormat = workbookPartSource.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellStyleFormats.Descendants<CellFormat>().ToList()[int.Parse(cellFormat.FormatId)];

                    if (workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellStyleFormats.Descendants<CellFormat>().ToList().Count > int.Parse(cellFormat.FormatId) &&

                        workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellStyleFormats.Descendants<CellFormat>().ToList()[int.Parse(cellFormat.FormatId)].OuterXml == cellStyleFormat.OuterXml)

                    {

                        cellStyleFormatIndex = (uint)int.Parse(cellFormat.FormatId);

                    }

                    else

                    {

                        CellFormat cellStyleFormatClone = CellFormatClone(workbookPartSource, workbookPartDestination, cacheBorder, cacheFill, cacheFont, cacheNumberFormat, cellStyleFormat);

                        workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellStyleFormats.Append(cellStyleFormatClone);

                        cellStyleFormatIndex = (uint)workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellStyleFormats.Descendants<CellFormat>().ToList().IndexOf(cellStyleFormatClone);

                        cacheCellStyleFormat.Add(cellFormat.FormatId.Value, cellStyleFormatIndex);

                    }

                }

                cellFormatClone.FormatId = cellStyleFormatIndex;

            }

            workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Append(cellFormatClone);

            cellFormatIndex = (uint)workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Descendants<CellFormat>().ToList().IndexOf(cellFormatClone);

            cacheCellFormat.Add(cell.StyleIndex.Value, cellFormatIndex);



        }

        return cellFormatIndex;

    }



    private static CellFormat CellFormatClone(WorkbookPart workbookPartSource, WorkbookPart workbookPartDestination, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheBorder, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheFill, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheFont, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheNumberFormat, CellFormat cellFormat)

    {

        CellFormat cellFormatClone = new CellFormat();

        cellFormatClone.ApplyAlignment = cellFormat.ApplyAlignment;

        cellFormatClone.ApplyBorder = cellFormat.ApplyBorder;

        cellFormatClone.ApplyFill = cellFormat.ApplyFill;

        cellFormatClone.ApplyFont = cellFormat.ApplyFont;

        cellFormatClone.ApplyNumberFormat = cellFormat.ApplyNumberFormat;

        cellFormatClone.ApplyProtection = cellFormat.ApplyProtection;

        cellFormatClone.PivotButton = cellFormat.PivotButton;

        cellFormatClone.QuotePrefix = cellFormat.QuotePrefix;

        GetBorder(workbookPartSource, workbookPartDestination, cacheBorder, cellFormat, cellFormatClone);

        GetFill(workbookPartSource, workbookPartDestination, cacheFill, cellFormat, cellFormatClone);

        GetFont(workbookPartSource, workbookPartDestination, cacheFont, cellFormat, cellFormatClone);

        GetNumberFormat(workbookPartSource, workbookPartDestination, cacheNumberFormat, cellFormat, cellFormatClone);

        if (cellFormat.Protection != null)

            cellFormatClone.Protection = (Protection)cellFormat.Protection.Clone();

        if (cellFormat.Alignment != null)

            cellFormatClone.Alignment = (Alignment)cellFormat.Alignment.Clone();

        return cellFormatClone;

    }



    private static void GetNumberFormat(WorkbookPart workbookPartSource, WorkbookPart workbookPartDestination, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheNumberFormat, CellFormat cellFormat, CellFormat cellFormatClone)

    {

        uint numberFormatIndex = 0;

        if (cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value != 0)

        {

            if (cacheNumberFormat.Keys.Contains(cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value))

            {

                numberFormatIndex = cacheNumberFormat[cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value];

            }

            else

            {

                NumberingFormat numberFormat = workbookPartSource.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Descendants<NumberingFormat>().Where(nf => nf.NumberFormatId.Value == uint.Parse(cellFormat.NumberFormatId)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (numberFormat != null)
                {
                    if (workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats != null)
                    {
                        if (workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Descendants<NumberingFormat>().ToList().Count > int.Parse(cellFormat.NumberFormatId) &&
                        workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Descendants<NumberingFormat>().ToList()[int.Parse(cellFormat.NumberFormatId)].OuterXml == numberFormat.OuterXml)
                        {
                            cellFormatClone.NumberFormatId = (uint)int.Parse(cellFormat.NumberFormatId);
                            return;
                        }

                        NumberingFormat nfclone = new NumberingFormat();
                        nfclone.FormatCode = numberFormat.FormatCode;
                        nfclone.NumberFormatId = workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Descendants<NumberingFormat>().Max(nf => nf.NumberFormatId.Value) + 1;

                        workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.Append(nfclone);
                        numberFormatIndex = nfclone.NumberFormatId;
                        cacheNumberFormat.Add(cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value, numberFormatIndex);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    numberFormatIndex = cellFormat.NumberFormatId;
                }
            }

            cellFormatClone.NumberFormatId = numberFormatIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            cellFormatClone.NumberFormatId = 0;
        }
    }



    private static void GetFont(WorkbookPart workbookPartSource, WorkbookPart workbookPartDestination, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheFont, CellFormat cellFormat, CellFormat cellFormatClone)

    {

        uint fontIndex;

        if (cellFormat.FontId.Value != 0)

        {

            if (cacheFont.Keys.Contains(cellFormat.FontId.Value))

            {

                fontIndex = cacheFont[cellFormat.FontId.Value];

            }

            else

            {

                Font font = workbookPartSource.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts.Descendants<Font>().ToList()[int.Parse(cellFormat.FontId)];

                if (workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts.Descendants<Font>().ToList().Count > int.Parse(cellFormat.FontId) &&

               workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts.Descendants<Font>().ToList()[int.Parse(cellFormat.FontId)].OuterXml == font.OuterXml)

                {

                    cellFormatClone.FontId = (uint)int.Parse(cellFormat.FontId);

                    return;

                }

                Font fontClone = new Font();

                if (font.Bold != null)

                    fontClone.Bold = (Bold)font.Bold.Clone();

                if (font.Color != null)

                    fontClone.Color = (Color)font.Color.Clone();

                if (font.Condense != null)

                    fontClone.Condense = (Condense)font.Condense.Clone();

                if (font.Extend != null)

                    fontClone.Extend = (Extend)font.Extend.Clone();

                if (font.FontCharSet != null)

                    fontClone.FontCharSet = (FontCharSet)font.FontCharSet.Clone();

                if (font.FontName != null)

                    fontClone.FontName = (FontName)font.FontName.Clone();

                if (font.FontScheme != null)

                    fontClone.FontScheme = (FontScheme)font.FontScheme.Clone();

                if (font.FontSize != null)

                    fontClone.FontSize = (FontSize)font.FontSize.Clone();

                if (font.Italic != null)

                    fontClone.Italic = (Italic)font.Italic.Clone();

                if (font.Outline != null)

                    fontClone.Outline = (Outline)font.Outline.Clone();

                if (font.Shadow != null)

                    fontClone.Shadow = (Shadow)font.Shadow.Clone();

                if (font.Strike != null)

                    fontClone.Strike = (Strike)font.Strike.Clone();

                if (font.Underline != null)

                    fontClone.Underline = (Underline)font.Underline.Clone();

                if (font.VerticalTextAlignment != null)

                    fontClone.VerticalTextAlignment = (VerticalTextAlignment)font.VerticalTextAlignment.Clone();

                if (font.FontFamilyNumbering != null)

                    fontClone.FontFamilyNumbering = (FontFamilyNumbering)font.FontFamilyNumbering.Clone();





                workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts.Append(fontClone);

                fontIndex = (uint)workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts.Descendants<Font>().ToList().IndexOf(fontClone);

                cacheFont.Add(cellFormat.FontId.Value, fontIndex);

            }

            cellFormatClone.FontId = fontIndex;

        }

        else

        {

            cellFormatClone.FontId = 0;

        }

    }



    private static void GetFill(WorkbookPart workbookPartSource, WorkbookPart workbookPartDestination, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheFill, CellFormat cellFormat, CellFormat cellFormatClone)

    {

        uint fillIndex;

        if (cellFormat.FillId.Value != 0)

        {

            if (cacheFill.Keys.Contains(cellFormat.FillId.Value))

            {

                fillIndex = cacheFill[cellFormat.FillId.Value];

            }

            else

            {

                Fill fill = workbookPartSource.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.Descendants<Fill>().ToList()[int.Parse(cellFormat.FillId)];

                if (workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.Descendants<Fill>().ToList().Count > int.Parse(cellFormat.FillId) &&

                  workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.Descendants<Fill>().ToList()[int.Parse(cellFormat.FillId)].OuterXml == fill.OuterXml)

                {

                    cellFormatClone.FillId = (uint)int.Parse(cellFormat.FillId);

                    return;

                }

                Fill fillclone = new Fill();

                if (fill.GradientFill != null)

                    fillclone.GradientFill = (GradientFill)fill.GradientFill.Clone();

                if (fill.PatternFill != null)

                    fillclone.PatternFill = (PatternFill)fill.PatternFill.Clone();



                workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.Append(fillclone);

                fillIndex = (uint)workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.Descendants<Fill>().ToList().IndexOf(fillclone);

                cacheFill.Add(cellFormat.FillId.Value, fillIndex);

            }

            cellFormatClone.FillId = fillIndex;

        }

        else

        {

            cellFormatClone.FillId = 0;

        }

    }



    private static void GetBorder(WorkbookPart workbookPartSource, WorkbookPart workbookPartDestination, Dictionary<uint, uint> cacheBorder, CellFormat cellFormat, CellFormat cellFormatClone)

    {

        uint borderIndex;

        if (cellFormat.BorderId.Value != 0)

        {

            if (cacheBorder.Keys.Contains(cellFormat.BorderId.Value))

            {

                borderIndex = cacheBorder[cellFormat.BorderId.Value];

            }

            else

            {

                Border border = workbookPartSource.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Borders.Descendants<Border>().ToList()[int.Parse(cellFormat.BorderId)];

                if (workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Borders.Descendants<Border>().ToList().Count > int.Parse(cellFormat.BorderId) &&

                    workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Borders.Descendants<Border>().ToList()[int.Parse(cellFormat.BorderId)].OuterXml == border.OuterXml)

                {

                    cellFormatClone.BorderId = (uint)int.Parse(cellFormat.BorderId);

                    return;

                }

                Border borderclone = new Border();

                if (border.StartBorder != null)

                    borderclone.StartBorder = (StartBorder)border.StartBorder.Clone();

                if (border.EndBorder != null)

                    borderclone.EndBorder = (EndBorder)border.EndBorder.Clone();

                if (border.LeftBorder != null)

                    borderclone.LeftBorder = (LeftBorder)border.LeftBorder.Clone();

                if (border.RightBorder != null)

                    borderclone.RightBorder = (RightBorder)border.RightBorder.Clone();

                if (border.TopBorder != null)

                    borderclone.TopBorder = (TopBorder)border.TopBorder.Clone();

                if (border.BottomBorder != null)

                    borderclone.BottomBorder = (BottomBorder)border.BottomBorder.Clone();

                if (border.DiagonalBorder != null)

                    borderclone.DiagonalBorder = (DiagonalBorder)border.DiagonalBorder.Clone();

                if (border.VerticalBorder != null)

                    borderclone.VerticalBorder = (VerticalBorder)border.VerticalBorder.Clone();

                if (border.HorizontalBorder != null)

                    borderclone.HorizontalBorder = (HorizontalBorder)border.HorizontalBorder.Clone();



                workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Borders.Append(borderclone);

                borderIndex = (uint)workbookPartDestination.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Borders.Descendants<Border>().ToList().IndexOf(borderclone);

                cacheBorder.Add(cellFormat.BorderId.Value, borderIndex);

            }

            cellFormatClone.BorderId = borderIndex;

        }

        else

        {

            cellFormatClone.BorderId = 0;

        }

    }



    private static int InsertSharedStringItem_(string text, SharedStringTablePart shareStringPart)

    {
        // If the part does not contain a SharedStringTable, create one.
        if (shareStringPart.SharedStringTable == null)
        {
            shareStringPart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();
        }

        int i = 0;

        // Iterate through all the items in the SharedStringTable. If the text already exists, return its index.
        foreach (SharedStringItem item in shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>())
        {
            if (item.InnerText == text)
            {
                return i;
            }

            i++;
        }

        // The text does not exist in the part. Create the SharedStringItem and return its index.
        shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text(text)));
        shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Save();

        return i;
    }



    private static void DeleteWorkSheet(WorkbookPart wbPart, string sheetToDelete)

    {

        string Sheetid = "";





        // Get the pivot Table Parts

        IEnumerable<PivotTableCacheDefinitionPart> pvtTableCacheParts = wbPart.PivotTableCacheDefinitionParts;

        Dictionary<PivotTableCacheDefinitionPart, string> pvtTableCacheDefinationPart = new Dictionary<PivotTableCacheDefinitionPart, string>();

        foreach (PivotTableCacheDefinitionPart Item in pvtTableCacheParts)

        {

            PivotCacheDefinition pvtCacheDef = Item.PivotCacheDefinition;

            //Check if this CacheSource is linked to SheetToDelete

            var pvtCahce = pvtCacheDef.Descendants<CacheSource>().Where(s => s.WorksheetSource.Sheet == sheetToDelete);

            if (pvtCahce.Count() > 0)

            {

                pvtTableCacheDefinationPart.Add(Item, Item.ToString());

            }

        }

        foreach (var Item in pvtTableCacheDefinationPart)

        {

            wbPart.DeletePart(Item.Key);

        }

        //Get the SheetToDelete from workbook.xml

        Sheet theSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetToDelete).FirstOrDefault();

        if (theSheet == null)

        {

            // The specified sheet doesn't exist.

        }

        //Store the SheetID for the reference

        Sheetid = theSheet.SheetId;



        // Remove the sheet reference from the workbook.

        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id));

        theSheet.Remove();



        // Delete the worksheet part.

        wbPart.DeletePart(worksheetPart);



        //Get the DefinedNames

        var definedNames = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<DefinedNames>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (definedNames != null)

        {

            foreach (DefinedName Item in definedNames)

            {

                // This condition checks to delete only those names which are part of Sheet in question

                if (Item.Text.Contains(sheetToDelete + "!"))

                    Item.Remove();

            }

        }

        // Get the CalculationChainPart 

        //Note: An instance of this part type contains an ordered set of references to all cells in all worksheets in the 

        //workbook whose value is calculated from any formula



        CalculationChainPart calChainPart;

        calChainPart = wbPart.CalculationChainPart;

        if (calChainPart != null)

        {

            var calChainEntries = calChainPart.CalculationChain.Descendants<CalculationCell>().Where(c => c.SheetId == Sheetid);

            foreach (CalculationCell Item in calChainEntries)

            {

                Item.Remove();

            }

            if (calChainPart.CalculationChain.Count() == 0)

            {

                wbPart.DeletePart(calChainPart);

            }

        }



        // Save the workbook.

        wbPart.Workbook.Save();

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

After spending many hours on the problem of copying the entire sheet, I finally found a solution. The CloneSheet method copies the entire sheet (content + style) to a new sheet with a new name.

```
    static void CloneSheet(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument, string sheetName, string clonedSheetName)
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        WorksheetPart sourceSheetPart = GetWorkSheetPart(workbookPart, sheetName);
        Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();

        SpreadsheetDocument tempSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(new MemoryStream(), spreadsheetDocument.DocumentType);
        WorkbookPart tempWorkbookPart = tempSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
        WorksheetPart tempWorksheetPart = tempWorkbookPart.AddPart(sourceSheetPart);
        WorksheetPart clonedSheet = workbookPart.AddPart(tempWorksheetPart);

        Sheet copiedSheet = new Sheet();
        copiedSheet.Name = clonedSheetName;
        copiedSheet.Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(clonedSheet);
        copiedSheet.SheetId = (uint)sheets.ChildElements.Count + 1;
        sheets.Append(copiedSheet);
    }
```

Comment: this works well though above code clones the sheet in same workbook. What if I need to clone the sheet and copy the cloned sheet to new workbook? I have tried but not able to make it work i.e. clone and copy to new workbook. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

the fact of assigning :

```
copiedSheet.SheetId = (uint)sheets.ChildElements.Count + 1;
```

is not correct because this SheetId could be taken.
instead you can write :

```
copiedSheet.SheetId = newSheetId (workbookPart);
```

where newsheetId is defined so :

```
private UInt32Value NewSheetId(WorkbookPart workbookPart)
    {
        UInt32Value resultat = 0;
        foreach (Sheet sheet in workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>())
        {
            if (sheet.SheetId > resultat)
                resultat = sheet.SheetId;
        }
        return resultat + 1;
    }
```