# C# OpenXML copy Sheets from one excel document to another

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, xlsx

I have one excel file with 3 sheets, And I have another excel file with 2 sheets

As a result I want to get one excel file with 5 sheets.

I am using openXml. Also in excel file I have filtered and sorted columns, pivot table..

Tried this solutions :
[C# OpenXML copy and paste excel sheet to new workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856596/c-sharp-openxml-copy-and-paste-excel-sheet-to-new-workbook)

but some of them copying sheets only in one document, and one solution looks very cumbersome and doesn`t copy pivot..

Maybe there is some simple solution for copying?